# location.search does not update correctly - React - ReactRouterDomV5

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

In My App Functional Component I Define a Function That Should be Call Once The User Clicked On The Search Button In My `MainHeader` Functional Component.

```
function App(props) {
    const location = useLocation();
    const [movies, setMovies] = useState(DUMMY_MOVIES);
    
    const filterMovies = () => {
        console.log(location.search);
    }
    
    return (
        <MainHeader onFilterMovies={filterMovies}>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" exact>
                    <Redirect to="/movies" />
                </Route>
                <Route path="/movies" exact>
                    <Movies movies={movies} />
                </Route>
                <Route path="/movies/:movieId">
                    <MovieDetails />
                </Route>
            </Switch>
        </MainHeader>
    );
}
```

In The `MainHeader` Component There Is A Submit Handler That Will Execute Once The User Click the Search Button, And In There(SubmitHandler) I Append `searchTerm` As A Key And `searchTermValue` As The Value Of The Query Parameter And Replace The Page With `` location.replace(`/movies?searchTerm=${searchTermValue}`) ``.
And Finally I Call The OnFitlerMovies Whitch I Receive From `props` To Inform The `App` Component That We're DONE!

In `App` Functional Component Where I Define The `FiltrerMovies` Function, I Simply Log The Query Parameter Value To The Console.

But The Value Witch I Receive Is The Previous Value Of The Query Parameter.
I Mean When I Enter `something` In The Search Input And Then Click The Search Button I Receive It In `FilterMovies` Method As An Empty String, But The Next Time, Even If I Dont Enter Anything(I Mean A Empty String), The Correct Value For The Previous Time Get Logged!

```
const MainHeader = (props) => {
    const history = useHistory();
    const searchTermInputRef = useRef();
    
    const submitHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        
        const searchTermValue = searchTermInputRef.current.value.trim();
        
        history.replace(`/movies?searchTerm=${searchTermValue}`);
        
        props.onFilterMovies();
    };
...
```

My Guess Is That We Can't Use ReactRouterDomV5 Hooks Inside of A Component Witch Is Not In `Route` Component.

Now How Can I Solve This Problem?

Comment: `filterMovies` is a stale enclosure over the `location.search` value, so you see the stale value. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I just want to access the correct query parameter value

Comment: Ok, yeah, that part is clear. What are you trying to use that value to do? Is the goal to simply log the current value?

Comment: I want to use it as search term for filtering the movies array.

Comment: const filteredMovies = movies.filter(m => m.name.includes(searchTerm)); => is what i wanna do next

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The `filterMovies` callback has a stale closure over the `location.search` value, so you see the stale value.

## Solution

Use a `useEffect` hook to log the updated `location.search` value.

Example:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(location.search);
}, [location.search]);
```

If you are wanting to use the querySearch param to filter the `movies` state prior to passing it to the `Movies` component do this inline.

Example:

```
function App() {
  const location = useLocation();
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState(DUMMY_MOVIES);

  const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
  const searchTerm = searchPararms.get("searchTerm");

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(location.search);
  }, [location.search]);

  return (
    <MainHeader>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact>
          <Redirect to="/movies" />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/movies" exact>
          <Movies
            movies={movies.filter(movie => {
              if (searchTerm) {
                return movie.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase());
              }
              return true;
            })}
          />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/movies/:movieId">
          <MovieDetails />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </MainHeader>
  );
}
```

If you want to improve performance then use the `useMemo` hook to memoize the filtered movies value.

Example:

```
const location = useLocation();
const [movies, setMovies] = useState(DUMMY_MOVIES);

const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
const searchTerm = searchPararms.get("searchTerm");

const filteredMovies = useMemo(() => {
  return movies.filter(movie => {
    if (searchTerm) {
      return movie.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase());
    }
    return true;
  }
}, [movies, searchTerm]);

...

<Route path="/movies" exact>
  <Movies movies={filteredMovies} />
</Route>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can Use componentDidMount() or in functional base component use following code

```
const redirect = location.search;
useEffect(() => {
//necessary code
}, [redirect])
```

for React Router 6

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
const location = useLocation();
const redirect = location.search;
```